# Concatenate in jQuery Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simple problem. I have a js variable I want to be concatenated too within a jQuery selector. However it is not working. No errors are popping up either. What is wrong? How do I correctly concatenate a variable to some text in a jQuery selector.

```
<select class="form-control" name="taille"  id="{{Product.id~'/taille'}}">
<option>Taille</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select>
```

and in jquery Used this code for get the id for selected select

```
$('select[name="taille"]').focusin(function(){ 
    var idElement = $(this).attr('id'); 
    var arr = idElement.split('/');
```

and it's work very good but the problem i wan append option for selected select by id I try many code and no one work for exemple :

```
$('#'+arr[0]+'/taille')
    .find('option')
    .remove()
    .end()
    .append('<option value="whatever">text</option>')
    .val('whatever')
;
```

Please help and thanks.

Comment: Use `$('select[name="taille"]').html('<option value="whatever">text</option>').val('whatever')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('[id="' + arr[0] + '/taille"]')
```

---

Or you need to escape the meta-character (`/`) using `\\`.

```
$('#' + arr[0] + '\\/taille')
```

---

Check [documentation of jQuery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) :

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  ``` !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^``{|}~ ```) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: `\\`. For example, an element with `id="foo.bar"`, can use the selector `$("#foo\\.bar")`. The W3C CSS specification contains the [complete set of rules regarding valid CSS selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier). Also useful is the blog entry by Mathias Bynens on [CSS character escape sequences for identifiers](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes).

---

I think you are trying to get the same element using its own `id`. If `yes` then there is no need of that use `this` which refer the same element. Although there is no need to remove and append again just use **[`html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/)** which will remove existing.

```
$('select[name="taille"]').focusin(function(){ 
   $(this).html('<option value="whatever" selected>text</option>');
});
```

Comment: As said in my answer `.find('option')
    .remove()
    .end()
    .append` ==> `.html()`.